# Histogram in MatLab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm a little bit stuck on how to plot a histogram in MatLab, and typing `help hist` in MatLab does not make me any wiser.  So I would appreciate any help!

Basically my problem is very simple.  I have a vector, `V`, with five values, where each value represent the volume of a certain layer of the Earth.  I simply want to create a histogram of these data, where the x-axis in my histogram should say "Inner Core", "Outer Core", etc., while the y-axis will display the volume.  I've tried using the hist-command in various ways, but I can't get this to work.  For instance, if I just type `hist(V)`, the volume-values actually show up on the x-axis, and not the y-axis.

If anyone can help me how to make this simple histogram I will be very grateful!  According to the instructions on my homework, I have to use the hist-command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually what is a bar plot.

```
bar([4,20,10,3,8])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I actually know how to use the bar-command, and I can very easily get my desired histogram by using the code:        layers = [1:5];
bar(layers, V)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Inner Core', 'Outer Core', 'Inner Mantle', 'Outer Core', 'Crust'})
ylabel('Volume')                                                                                                                        The problem is that this is a homework problem, and it specifically specifies that we should use the 'hist' command which, frankly, I do not find very intuitive.

Comment: But you can't histogram a vector with only 5 values, they would all end up in the same bin...

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  I think I will e-mail my professor and ask if it is OK to use the 'bar'-command.